# Empty space under grid when using grid-template-column

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I'm setting up ad grid using grid.
Here is code:

```css
.container: {
    display: grid;
    padding: 24px;
    grid-gap: 1rem 1.5rem;
    overflow: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <TileComponent>
   ...N times...
</div>
```

It is working good except empty space, so how to remove it?

I dont want to make fixed number of columns or rows. Columns depend on screen size and rows depend on number of tiles/files.
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided, create a working snippet (Ctrl + M) that has the extra space under your container.

Comment: @ZachJensz I'll try to reproduce it. It appears that this bug is only in my code in this place. When I inspect with devtools it shows that height is not that big. But container element has height out of nowhere. What's strange is that in other place where I use that tiles component that empty space is not there.

Comment: @ZachJensz I solved the problem by setting width to 100%. Idk how it works)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of the grid to 100% will solve the issue.